# How to get photo path after sharing photo from gallery to my MAUI .NET Android application

Tags: android, android-activity, maui

I want to share photo to my MAUI .NET Android application. The only thing I am getting at the moment is photo URI.

Here is my MainActivity.cs:

```
[Activity(Theme = "@style/Maui.SplashTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation | ConfigChanges.UiMode | ConfigChanges.ScreenLayout | ConfigChanges.SmallestScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Density, LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTask)]
[IntentFilter(new[] { "android.intent.action.SEND" }, Categories = new[] { "android.intent.category.DEFAULT" }, DataMimeType = "*/*")]
[IntentFilter(new[] { "android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" }, Categories = new[] { "android.intent.category.DEFAULT" }, DataMimeType = "*/*")]
public class MainActivity : MauiAppCompatActivity
{
    protected override void OnNewIntent(Intent? intent)
    {
        base.OnNewIntent(intent);
        if (intent.Type == "image/jpeg")
        {
            var data = intent?.ClipData?.GetItemAt(0);
        }
    }
}
```

How can I get photo path, to display it in my application?

Comment: You can use the uri too to display. What is the problem?

Comment: @blackapps Later I have to send that photo to Sharepoint. At the moment I am unable to get content of it using URI.

Comment: Well that is strange. That should not be a problem at all. But .. we dont know what you do..

Comment: @blackapps Generally I want to be able to save photo content and name in sharepoint using my application. One of the ways to do it must be shareing photo directly from phone gallery (not File Picker), displaying it in application and saving it in sharepoint. I don't know how to get content and file name when I am using share from phone gallery.

Comment: You can open an InputStream for the uri and then read from the stream to get the content.

Comment: `One of the ways to do it must be shareing photo directly from phone gallery (not File Picker) ...` What do you have in mind how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you deal with content URIs (content://) instead of direct file paths when you share a photo to your MAUI.NET Android application and receive a URI.

Here's how you can get an image from a URI and display it in your MAUI application:

1. Access the URI: As you've identified, the shared intent provides a URI to the photo. Use this URI to access the photo.
2. Read the InputStream: Use the content resolver to open an input stream for the content URI.
3. Convert to a Displayable Format: Since you can't directly use the file path in scoped storage, convert the input stream to a format that your app can display, such as a StreamImageSource or saving it temporarily to your app's private storage.

**Step 1** : Setting Up MainActivity.cs

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Microsoft.Maui;
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace YourNamespace
{
    [Activity(Theme = "@style/Maui.SplashTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation | ConfigChanges.UiMode | ConfigChanges.ScreenLayout | ConfigChanges.SmallestScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Density, LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTask)]
    [IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionSend }, Categories = new[] { Intent.CategoryDefault }, DataMimeType = "image/*")]
    public class MainActivity : MauiAppCompatActivity
    {
        protected override void OnNewIntent(Intent? intent)
        {
            base.OnNewIntent(intent);
            HandleIntent(intent);
        }

        private void HandleIntent(Intent? intent)
        {
            if (intent?.Type?.StartsWith("image/") == true)
            {
                // Assuming single image share
                Android.Net.Uri imageUri = intent.Data ?? intent.ClipData?.GetItemAt(0)?.Uri;
                if (imageUri != null)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        // Get InputStream from the Uri
                        using var inputStream = ContentResolver.OpenInputStream(imageUri);
                        
                        // Convert InputStream to a MemoryStream for easier handling
                        var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
                        inputStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
                        memoryStream.Position = 0;
                        
                        DisplayImage(memoryStream);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"Error accessing shared image: {ex.Message}");
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private void DisplayImage(MemoryStream memoryStream)
        {
            var imageSource = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new 
            MemoryStream(memoryStream.ToArray()));

            if (App.MainPageInstance != null)
            {
               MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
               {
                  App.MainPageInstance.UpdateImage(imageSource);
               });
            }
        }

    }
}
```

**Step 2** : Displaying the Image in Your Application

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="YourNamespace.MainPage">

    <VerticalStackLayout Spacing="25" Padding="30">
        <Image x:Name="SharedImage" />
    </VerticalStackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

And in your MainPage.xaml.cs, add a method to update the image:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void UpdateImage(ImageSource imageSource)
    {
        SharedImage.Source = imageSource;
    }
}
```

**Step 3** : Expose MainPage Instance

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public static MainPage MainPageInstance { get; private set; }

    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MainPage mainPage = new MainPage();
        MainPage = mainPage;
        MainPageInstance = mainPage;
    }
}
```

Οbviously, the structure of the code does not follow any patterns like MVVM, you could modify it to follow them and improve the code.